# Link in AJAX HTML response loses onclick after being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

I have an element containing data from an AJAX request. The AJAX data is returned from another page. The returned data in the element contains a link, which when clicked, opens a jQuery overlay. The onclick event is attached to the link (a onclick="...") from the external data, and the overlay function is on my main page.

This all works fine until the user clicks the link which opens the overlay. When the overlay is closed, the link becomes disabled, losing its onclick event, and the overlay cannot then be reopened.

Is this a focusing problem or do I somehow have to rebind the event to that link? I'm not sure what is going on here, or how to fix it, I hope some kind person can help me out.

This is what loads the external data in to the element:

```
function load_upload_queue() {
    $.ajax({ type : 'GET', url : myDomain,
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(data) { $('#myElement').html(data); },
    error : function() { // do something }
    });
}
```

This is the link inside of the element, which comes from AJAX call above:

```
<a onclick="show_error_overlay(id)">Show Errors</a>
```

This is my open overlay function, sitting on the main page:

```
function show_error_overlay(token) {
    $("#show_error_overlay").overlay({
        mask: '#111111',
        close: "a.closeOverlayBtn",
        closeOnClick: false,
        closeOnEsc: false,
        load: true,
        onLoad: function() { // do something },
        onClose: function() { // do something }
    });
}
```

Any help gratefully received, any questions please do not hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Firefox+Firebug to monitor whether that A tag is being touched (moved, changed) by anything as the overlay opens and closes. See if it maintains the same position; most importantly, check if it still has the onclick value after the overlay goes away. Inspect your "do somethings" in onLoad and onClose for any code that may be doing something to that link. Also, check for JS errors, especially during/after closing the overlay - sometimes errors interrupt the process, leaving unrelated things in unexpected state, causing unrelated problems.